# When using ActiveMerchant, is it secure to initialize it when application starts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

Some people initialize the active merchant gateway when the application starts inside `/config/environments`  like this :

```
config.after_initialize do
    paypal_options = {
        login: ENV['PAYPAL_LOGIN'],
        password: ENV['PAYPAL_PASSWORD'],
        signature: ENV['PAYPAL_SIGNATURE']
    }
    ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)
end
```

Some initiate it in a private method only when needed like this :

```
paypal_express_params = {
  login: ENV['PAYPAL_LOGIN'],
  password: ENV['PAYPAL_PASSWORD'],
  signature: ENV['PAYPAL_SIGNATURE']
}

gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_express_params)
```

What is the most secure option and why?

Comment: Just because I am curious, would you mind to elaborate? Why do you think one would be more secure than the other? I would really expect them to similar security-wise, do you have reason to believe it's not?

Comment: @Ninigi Actually I thought putting it on a private method and initiating only when needed can be secure. When we initialize at first it stays in the memory right? not secure right? Sorry im a bit new!

Comment: @Ninigi So am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. IMO if you are worried about things in the memory, your security concerns are going a bit too deep there. If anyone is able to enter you servers memory, than you are in the deepest trouble possible and nothing you do in your code will help you there.
Or to say the same thing in different words: An attacker must never have access to your server (wont even talk about memory) or you are in deep trouble, no matter how "secure" your code is :)